# Random Integer Between 2 Numbers Excluding In-Between Terms

Tags: c#, random

How can I generate random number between 0 and 2 excluding 1? The function I am currently using is:

```
public static int DecRandomNumber(int min, int max)
{
      lock (syncLock)
      {
           // synchronize
           int val = Convert.ToInt32(random.Next(0, 3));
           return(val == 1 ? 2 : 0);
      }
}
```

However this is *not at all generalized* **as I am not using min and max and happen to know that min will always be 1 and max be 3**. 
What's the best way to achieve this? 
Thanks.

Comment: Say min is 1 and max is 10, you want to generate a random number that is either 1 or 10 (and nothing else)?

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc Exactly!

Comment: If you're excluding all "in-between" terms, you're just picking from A or B with a 50% chance of picking each one. Just generate a rand.NextDouble(), and if it's less than .5 go with A.

Comment: btw.: You random number is much more likely to be 0 than 2. (approx. 66% chance for the function to return 0)

Comment: Any reason for the downvote please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple ways. One could be to generate a random number from 0 to 1 and multiply by two:

```
int val = random.Next(0, 2); // gives 0 or 1
return val * 2; // returns 0 * 2 = 0 or 1 * 2 = 2 with equal probability
```

Or you could generate a double and use a ternary, to control the probability:

```
return random.NextDouble() < 0.5 ? 0 : 2;
```

Comment: The solutions seems very reasonable. Thanks.

Comment: Didn't OP want to use the min and max parameters passed?

Comment: Well the question is a tedious bit ambiguous in that regard. The way I'm reading is that he wants the solution generalized. His comments seem to indicate that he does indeed want to use them.

Comment: @TroelsLarsen Yes it was a bit ambiguous. I just modified the second solution to use min and max.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Misunderstood your question, trying again. This solution uses your min & max values:

```
return random.Next() % 2 == 0 ? min : max;
```

Comment: This is probably the simplest way of doing it.

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc In general it's better to avoid the modulo operator to obtain a range of outcomes because of [modulo bias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984974/why-do-people-say-there-is-modulo-bias-when-using-a-random-number-generator).

Comment: @pjs: While that is true for low values of random generation, I think it is quite neglible using Next() without parameters will only have an extremely tiny bias (which is also mentioned in your link). If that bias is too large, OP shouldn't even use Random as it is slightly biased itself.

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc Whether bias will manifest or not for a particular case, it's a bad choice to use as your go-to tool.

Comment: @pjs: Modulo is not always bad. In the case of Next(), there are 2147483647 possible values. Of those values, 1073741824 are even, and 1073741823 are odd (Due to starting with 0 and ending with Int.MaxValue - 1). This means there is a slight bias, yes. But it is 0,50000000023% vs 0,49999999977%. If you cannot live with this bias, I would argue that you are doing something very specialized that would also require a better random number generator than Random. Since OP never mentioned any special requirements in this regard, I don't see your point.

Comment: @pjs I didn't know about modulo bias.  Thanks.  Although, I don't think it's that big of a bias with just generating between two numbers this way.

Comment: @TroelsLarsen You're right, it's not always bad.  However, it sometimes is. When there are two or more ways to do something, and one of them is known to screw up sometimes, the ways that don't screw up are better tools to have in your toolbox. It doesn't matter that the bias is negligible in this particular case, if you use modulo as your range tool for uniform random numbers you will get burned someday.

Comment: @pjs: Understanding WHY something CAN be bad is more important than absolute statements. In your linked example, it was bad because the distribution was 3/3/4. Using rng.Next(0, Int32.MaxValue-1) % 2 == 0 will have no bias other than the one imposed by the the RNG itself. Modulo is NOT introducing any bias at all when used correctly.

Comment: @TroelsLarsen Used "correctly" is the wrong phraseology, it implies there is always a correct way if only you would use it.  Used "when appropriate" would be better. The problem is that most people who are using it have no idea when it is or is not appropriate, and other techniques exist which don't suffer from that problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a funny question in general, but for anyone needing more functionality, I'd propose the following pseudo code for thought:

```
public class RandomBrokenSequence
{
   private List<int> items;
   private Random random;

   public RandomBrokenSequence()
   {
     items = new List<int>();
     random = new Random();
   }

   public int Next()
   {
     return items[random.Next(0,items.Count)];
   }

   public void Add(int item){ /*You get the idea*/ }
   public void RemoveIfFound(int item){ /*You get the idea*/ }

   public void AddRange(int start, int end){ /*You get the idea*/ }
   public void RemoveRange(int start, int end){ /*You get the idea*/ }
}
```

Then you could add range 0-100, and then say remove 7 and 15-25, or whatever your heart's content.  Essentially we just created a mapping.  This would be a little bit overboard if you were only needing two random values, but interestingly could be used in a scenario where your random set was changing.